# How can I make my tweets private?

Tags: twitter, privacy

I want my tweets on Twitter to remain private and not be visible to anyone except those I designate as being able to view.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I already mentioned this on a facebook thread, but it is worth mentioning again: If you are truly concerned about the privacy of twitter (or any social media) it would be prudent to communicate those messages in another format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check "**Protect my tweets**" on http://twitter.com/settings/account

> Only let people whom I approve follow
>   my tweets. If this is checked, your
>   future tweets will not be available
>   publicly. Tweets posted previously may
>   still be publicly visible in some
>   places.

[image: Protect your tweets]